# Cannot install enum package on Python3.6

Tags: pip, package, python-3.6

I am trying to run [this example](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html#test-case) on MacOS High Sierra. It requires installing the `page` package, which requires installing the `pytodos` package, which requires installing the `enum` package, installation of which fails.

```
$ python3 page_object_test_case.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "page_object_test_case.py", line 3, in <module>
    import page
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'page'
$ pip3 install page
...
Successfully installed click-6.7 page-1.0.16
$ python3 page_object_test_case.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "page_object_test_case.py", line 3, in <module>
    import page
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/page/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pytodos import todo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytodos'
$ pip3 install pytodos
Collecting pytodos
...
Collecting enum==0.4.6 (from pytodos)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0c/4e/1ea357e7783c756bb579333c1e4a026fb331371ee771f616ffedc781e531/enum-0.4.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/version.py:1: UserWarning: Module enum was already imported from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/enum.py, but /private/var/folders/h3/1znktv0s36j1fdqcdrr0zvcw0000gn/T/pip-install-jhfn7vc3/enum is being added to sys.path
      import pkg_resources
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/h3/1znktv0s36j1fdqcdrr0zvcw0000gn/T/pip-install-jhfn7vc3/enum/setup.py", line 24, in <module>
        version = main_module.__version__
    AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Note that I've tried to do the same on Ubuntu. And I had to repeat every step. However, installation of `enum` failed with this error instead:

```
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You went wrong at `pip install page`.

You were supposed to provide your own module `page.py`, as described [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html#page-object-classes).

`pip install page` pulled in some [garbage and unrelated/unmaintained projects from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/page/).